# How to reference different fields in Grails custom validator

Tags: validation, grails

I am trying to simply reference a different domain field(benefiaryname) from a transient field validator. How to accomplish this?

```
class Fytrnlt {
 transient Boolean firevalidation = false
 String checknum
 String bankcode
 String branchcode

 String benefiaryname

............


       firevalidation validator: {inputValue, obj ->



       // def CheckResult = obj.bannerService.documentValidation(inputValue, benefiaryname, null)

        def CheckResult = obj.bannerService.documentValidation(inputValue, {benefiaryname}, null)

        if (CheckResult != 1)
            return false
    } */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your validator function the obj variable is the current object, so, you should be able to simply reference `obj.beneficiaryname`.

Comment: Great, I missed that. I am having problems getting debug to work in intellij so I am a bit in the dark on some of this stuff. Appreciate your reply.